# How can I produce without schema as avro type with python?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I use below code and send message to kafka. It works.

But I want to send message without schema because I have schema on kafka topic. I register it first. I do not want to send schema everytime.

```
from confluent_kafka import avro
from confluent_kafka.avro import AvroProducer


value_schema_str = """
{
   "type":"record",
   "name":"myrecord",
   "fields":[
      {
         "name":"id",
         "type":[
            "null",
            "int"
         ],
         "default":null
      },
      {
         "name":"product",
         "type":[
            "null",
            "string"
         ],
         "default":null
      },
      {
         "name":"quantity",
         "type":[
            "null",
            "int"
         ],
         "default":null
      },
      {
         "name":"price",
         "type":[
            "null",
            "int"
         ],
         "default":null
      }
   ]
}
"""

key_schema_str = """
{
   "type":"record",
   "name":"key_schema",
   "fields":[
      {
         "name":"id",
         "type":"int"
      }
   ]
}
"""


def delivery_report(err, msg):
    """ Called once for each message produced to indicate delivery result.
        Triggered by poll() or flush(). """
    if err is not None:
        print('Message delivery failed: {}'.format(err))
    else:
        print('Message delivered to {} [{}]'.format(msg.topic(), msg.partition()))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    value_schema = avro.loads(value_schema_str)
    key_schema = avro.loads(key_schema_str)
    #value = {"id": 1, "product": "myProduct", "quantity": 10, "price": 100}
    key = {"id": 1}


    avroProducer = AvroProducer({
        'bootstrap.servers': '10.0.0.0:9092',
        'on_delivery': delivery_report,
        'schema.registry.url': 'http://10.0.0.0:8081'
    }, default_key_schema=key_schema, default_value_schema=value_schema)

    avroProducer.produce(topic='orders', key=key)
    avroProducer.flush()t
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I do not want to send schema everytime.

Avro **requires** a Schema. Full stop

> I have schema on kafka topic

Kafka topics do not have schemas. I assume you mean you have a schema in the registry? Then you must fetch that before you use it in your producer

```py
from confluent_kafka.avro import CachedSchemaRegistryClient
sr_client = CachedSchemaRegistryClient({'url': "http://10.0.0.0:8081"})
```

Then use the client to do a `get_schema` call

Comment: it gives this: `DeprecationWarning: CachedSchemaRegistry constructor is being deprecated. Use CachedSchemaRegistryClient(dict: config) instead.4`

Comment: 1) Not an error 2) Like it says, Use `CachedSchemaRegistryClient(dict: config)` instead... Same class. You used the wrong constructor

Answer (score 1):

**Using [`confluent-kafka-python`](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/)**

```
from confluent_kafka.avro.cached_schema_registry_client import CachedSchemaRegistryClient

sr = CachedSchemaRegistryClient({"url": "http://localhost:8081"})

value_schema = sr.get_latest_schema("orders-value")[1]
key_schema= sr.get_latest_schema("orders-key")[1]
```

**Using [`SchemaRegistryClient`](https://marcosschroh.github.io/python-schema-registry-client/client/)**

```
# pip install python-schema-registry-client
from schema_registry.client import SchemaRegistryClient


sr = SchemaRegistryClient('localhost:8081')
value_schema = sr.get_schema('orders-value', version='latest').schema
key_schema = sr.get_schema('orders-key', version='latest').schema
```

And finally:

```
from confluent_kafka import avro
from confluent_kafka.avro import AvroProducer


def delivery_report(err, msg):
    """ Called once for each message produced to indicate delivery result.
        Triggered by poll() or flush(). """
    if err is not None:
        print('Message delivery failed: {}'.format(err))
    else:
        print('Message delivered to {} [{}]'.format(msg.topic(), msg.partition()))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    value = {"id": 1, "product": "myProduct", "quantity": 10, "price": 100}
    key = {"id": 1}


    avroProducer = AvroProducer({
        'bootstrap.servers': '10.0.0.0:9092',
        'on_delivery': delivery_report,
        'schema.registry.url': 'http://10.0.0.0:8081'
    }, default_key_schema=key_schema, default_value_schema=value_schema)

    avroProducer.produce(topic='orders', key=key, value=value)
    avroProducer.flush()
```

Comment: error : `import python-schema-registry-client as sr
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: i did install python-schema-registry-client but it gives error invalid , i think import is wrong

Comment: so my answer is working even deprecated but this answer is not working

Comment: it gives this error `AttributeError: 'SchemaVersion' object has no attribute 'to_json'`

Comment: Have you tried using `to_json()` ? Which line does it cause this error?

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar Updated my answer. Let me know if it works now.

Comment: what have you changed?

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar I added `.schema` when using `get_schema`

Comment: still same error : `File "/home/ersin/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/confluent_kafka/avro/cached_schema_registry_client.py", line 216, in register
    body = {'schema': json.dumps(avro_schema.to_json())}
AttributeError: 'AvroSchema' object has no attribute 'to_json'`

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar Did you use `SchemaRegistryClient` or `confluent-kafka-python`?

Comment: from schema_registry.client import SchemaRegistryClient

Comment: Does it work with the code that I shared from `confluent-kafka-python` ?

Comment: it works for my answers code but id says deprecated

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar Okay. Stick to this one then. I'll try to figure out how to convert `AvroSchema` to `schema` so that it is compatible with confluent's `AvroProducer`

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar I also added one example which is more clear than yours. I think it should work fine.,

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar I've edited my `confluent-kafka-python` answer. You should not be able to instantiate `CachedSchemaRegistryClient`  without the deprecation warning.